# Combining event driven and real time elements in a single game

Tags: c#, game-engine

I'm trying to create a (very basic) game. The game is split into two distinct parts, and event driven part where nothing happens unless the player clicks buttons, and a real time element where the user clicks buttons but in response to real time events.

The best example I can think of is the Rome: Total War series. The campaign mode is pretty much entirely event driven, the battle mode is live. Football manager (management mode / match mode) is also similar.

I know it's a stupidly general question but how do you go about programming such a game? Are there any docs on this kind of thing?

Language I'd like to use if possible is C#

EDIT:

Example of code snippets:

```
void UpdateCar1(GameTime gameTime, float speed)
{
    a = (float)gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds * speed * (float)(90 * Math.PI / (180*2.5));
    X = Math.Cos(a)*100;
    Y = Math.Sin(a)*100;
    Car1Position.X = 100+(int)X;
    Car1Position.Y = 100+(int)Y;
}
```

This makes a `Car` "drive" around in a circle.

There's some code for detecting mouse button clicks on "buttons" - they just make the `Car` go faster or slower (edited to pseudo code for clarity).

```
if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && previousButtonState == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    if ("button click occured within faster button rectangle") { "go faster" }
    if ("button click occured within slower button rectangle") { "go slower" }
}
```

The above is all well and good for the Real Time elements of the game. However for the Event Driven stuff it seems clumsy, I don't need the game to update 60 times a second for that, I only need it to update if a button is pressed.

My question is whether there is a way to combine the two, as it clearly has been done with the above games.

Comment: Not one line of code yet?

Comment: Lots of tiny little test scripts to try out stuff, and a pretty good idea (well at least I think so) of class structure. No doubt it'll change though. I guess I'm asking this now before I go down a completely stupid path. Drawing buttons in XNA and constantly loading and unloading GUI elements seems a little clumsy when something like windows forms handles it so neatly (except of course that can't do real time stuff)

Comment: Then show us! This question will only render in downvotes.

Comment: Some code added above

Answer (score 0):

Put all the real time actions in a separate thread running the "game loop".

All events either push to a queue that the game loop then polls or set flags the game loop cn check.

This way all events are separated from the constantly running loop in a controlled way.

The game loop will be responsible for calling the "update" method for all objects which causes the objects to move, shoot or whatever it should be doing on it's own.

Or have I misunderstood the question?